# Android:Display the device time using joda in chat

Tags: android, timestamp, chat, jodatime

I need to show the device time in the chat messenger but it shows only the zone time.If I change the device time both time will be not same.

I want to display the current device time in Timestamp I used joda.Please check my code.

```
        DateTime createdAt = message.getCreatedAt();


        DateTimeZone dateTimeZone= DateTimeZone.getDefault();

        DateTimeFormatter fmtTimeBubble = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(LBUtil.TIME_AM_PM_FORMAT).withZone(dateTimeZone);

        viewHolder.dateTime.setText(fmtTimeBubble.print(createdAt));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below method for getting time according to any timezone, you have to pass 3 parameters as :

1. System Current time in millis.
2. Device timezone
3. And, format of time like (`MMM dd, hh:mm a`)

   ```
   public static String getFormatedTime(long dateTime,String timeZone, String format){
       String time = null;
       try{    
           Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
           cal.setTimeInMillis(dateTime);
           SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
           sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZone));
           time = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
       }
       catch(Exception e){
           //logger.log(Level.SEVERE,"\n ERROR**********, Exception during get formated time: "+e+"\n");       
       }
       return time;
   }
   ```

For Calling this method, you have to get device timezone programmatically :

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
TimeZone zone = calendar.getTimeZone();   
String timeZone = zone.getID();
```

Now Call this method :

```
  String msgAtTime =  getFormattedTime(System.currentTimeInMillis(), timezone, "MMM dd, hh:mm a");
```

Now, set return String in `textview`.

```
    msgTextVies.setText(msgAtTime);
```

Comment: thanks for you answer I want to show my code to you please can you check it out?